# How do I compute a formula using PHP from a string stored in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of products. Some products require special calculations in order to calculate shipping costs.

Currently, I am hardcoding the formulas as functions in my PHP code. But I would like to instead allow for the formulas to be entered and stored as a string in my MYSQL database.

For Example:

```
$quantity=5;
$shipping_rate=100;

SELECT shipping_formula FROM products WHERE product_id='1'
// DO QUERY

$shipping_formula_string=if($quantity>4){$shipping_cost=$shipping_rate*1.5}else{$shipping_cost=$shipping_rate} return $shipping_cost

$shipping_cost=do_calculation($shipping_formula_string);
```

Is this possible? I don't want to have to dig into my code everytime a new product is added.

Comment: May helpful for you : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html

Answer (score 0):

For security reason you should use the symfony expression language instead of eval. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/index.html
The advantage you will have are:

You ...

- can install it as standalone component
- can store the expression in database, or else where
- are save to use it
- ... and many more like tested and so on

Here a litte example from the docs:

```
$data = array('life' => 10, 'universe' => 10, 'everything' => 22);

echo $language->evaluate(
    'data["life"] + data["universe"] + data["everything"]',
    array(
        'data' => $data,
    )
);

// Will output 42
```

Comment: What? There's no point to involve another library for this case.

Comment: @Raptor in my opinion it strongly depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to give your user the possibility to enter own formulas, it´s always a very bad idea to use eval. And because it is not mentioned who should be able to create the formula, I strongly recommend to use an abstraction layer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible, that's what `eval()` function is for.
In your case it would be:

```
function do_calculation($code){
    return eval($code);
}
```

Now you miss semicolons at the end of statements and no quotes around that string - try to correct this:

```
$shipping_formula_string="if($quantity>4){$shipping_cost=$shipping_rate*1.5;}else{$shipping_cost=$shipping_rate;} return $shipping_cost;";
```

But the fact is that it is not safe solution. You had better store that code in static classes and call them when needed using autoload function.

Comment: You would have to be __very__ careful using eval for this depending on where the formulas come from and how they are sanitised.

Comment: I tried this and got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file  : eval()'d code".

Comment: You miss some semicolons at the end of statements - try to correct this `$shipping_formula_string=if($quantity>4){$shipping_cost=$shipping_rate*1.5;}else{$shipping_cost=$shipping_rate;} return $shipping_cost;`